# CFHTTP to get an embedded PDF for cfmail - mailparam

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfhttp, cfmail

Ok, I am not sure about this and am hoping to get some insight. Somewhat of a philosophy more than code specific coding question. Is this realistic or do I need to do something very differently?

I want to embed a PDF in an email as described at Ray's blog [Ray Camden Post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2009/1/22/Ask-a-Jedi-Sending-a-dynamic-PDF-via-email)
I am trying to get the PDF from the dynamic generator (existing code), NOT generating it on the page as described in Ray.

I have a url  basically (http://blah.com/index.cfm?pdfId=490)  (The real URL is private)
It works in a browser, I get a PDF that opens just fine in the browser.

When I try to open with CFHTTP I do not get any binary data.

```
<cfhttp url="#arguments.url#"
getasbinary="auto" method="get" 
result="urlContent"></cfhttp>
```

"FileContent" (empty/null)
"Header" (HTTP/1.1 200 OK ...)
"mimetype" (text, not pdf)
"Status" (200)

Can someone explain to me what is occurring with the browser .... ie why do I not get a PDF (file/CFHTTP) when the general link works?

Should I force 'binary' (I expected auto would work)?
Does the browser issue a new request?
FYI I am running CF 9.0.2 (developer)

Comment: *RE:Should I force 'binary'...?* Is the result *always* binary? What happens when you try it? *RE: It works in a browser* Is the URL external to *your* site? If so, have you checked for redirection? Use something FF's Live HTTP Headers to examine the successful http request from the browser. Maybe the site is redirecting or requires certain headers, like example "user-agent" (just a guess).

Comment: I swear I remember a bug with outputting binary data from cfhttp. The value was fine, it just didn't work if you output it. If you actually *save* the value and double click it in the file system, is it a valid pdf?

Comment: When I (forced it) looked at it In the debugger, it was a short string, like "{ED323A" Not long enough to be a PDF. I suspect you are right there might be a bug. I am going to give it one more stab with firebug, check for the redirection. (Curious to see what happens with that line of thought.

Comment: @user3005033 - Do you get the same result if you try saving it to a file like Raymond suggested? I had not thought of it, but a bug is definitely a possibility.

Comment: Ok, the code looks more like [@234d232321 (memory location?). I am trying to avoid going to disk (multi-department multi-instance ) load balanced server. I double checked the link, its correct, gives type=application/PDF(browser) vs text/html in the debugger.

Comment: Comments don't like enter ... anyway, saving to disk yielded the login screen ... either the framework threw an error or I need a session. (The PDF link works without a session, so not sure, register the cert? (http) Something different is happening from CF vs the browser. Can

Comment: PEBKAC. - Hidden session kept browser online, no (different) session for CF's call to itself. (secret hidden service event should cure the ills)

Answer (score 0):

I think Leigh and Ray answered the question, or helped me solve the problem. While debugging, saving the results to disk (rather than looking at it in the debugger ...) was the key to finding my error.

That and a good weekends rest did wonders too!.